# Error updating service references: Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework 'Silverlight, Version=v4.0'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I've recently ported over a Silverlight project into TFS 2010.  I am using VS2010.  After porting the project over to TFS we noticed the following error every time we attempt to update the service references in the Silverlight project: **"Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework 'Silverlight, Version=v4.0'.  This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted."**

Everything was working fine when the Solution was in Visual SourceSafe.  I've read some forums that suggest this may be some kind of path length issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was as expected related to the length of my new TFS paths.  Some of the paths were greater than 259 characters.  See http://praphullaparab.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/tfs-2010-error-tf205022-path-contains-more-than-the-allowed-259-characters/

Comment: This definitely works. This also resolves the odd "1 failed" message I was seeing at the end of otherwise successful builds with no errors in the output window. This is not specific to version control, but has to do with path lengths in general.

Comment: thanks for answer, I also try and find just because the folder name of my project is too long, I just **shorten some of the folder name in my path** and it's solved, I spend 8 hours to find it... another link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498624/visual-studio-2010-could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target-framework-netframewo