# VS resource editor fails with "Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2010: Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498624/visual-studio-2010-could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target-framework-netframewo)

I have a C# project with some resources inside Resources.resx. When I open this file in VS2010, I get error:

`Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.  This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.`

- The project compiles and runs fine - only the VS editor is broken.
- VS2010 is installed, which means .NET4 is installed too.
- This happen for everybody in the team, so it's not a single machine's .NET installation gone bad.
- The .csproj contains `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.
- [Could be a too-long path](http://wcfvs.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target.html), but the longest built files has a 139 chars full path, and that doesn't sound like much.

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498624/visual-studio-2010-could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target-framework-netframewo

Comment: That sounds like it is getting the info from TargetFrameworkAttribute. Are you tear getting 4.0 throughout? Do you have the VS service pack(s) installed, etc?