# Visual Studio 2012 Build failed but no error in error list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build

I started working on a project in Visual Studio 2012 professional, which has been written in Visual Studio 2010 SP1. In the solution is several projects. In one them is a problem,
when I set it as the startup project I have the message: `"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"`, but there is no errors in error list (others projects build success if them set as a startup). In the VS2010 there was no problem.

The only problem that I see is: in the `Properties -> Settings`, I get an error:

`"Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '. NETFramework, Version = v3.5'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted."`

Comment: Is .NET 3.5 installed on that machine?  VS2012 probably installs 4.0 by default, I think.  But if it's a legacy project which explicitly targets 3.5 then that version also needs to be installed.

Comment: You may find hte following useful http://traf-o-data.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/mystery-of-mscorlib.html

Comment: **4600** views, *3 question upvotes...* bah! Common people!!

Answer (score 6):

Close VS2012 and remove the (hidden) .suo file. Removing that file will solve the problem.
Set "show hidden files" via Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Folder Options.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen for a number of reasons. To find out the problem, Open Visual Studio Command Prompt and build your project or solution using MSBuild.

```
MSBuild <YourProject>.csproj
```

or

```
MSBuild <YourSolution>.sln
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a life saver. The VS Command Prompt showed me passing an Object to a function expecting a String parameter was the problem. Surprised that VS Error list didn't show it, you would expect both to use the same underlying technology.

Comment: how to write the command, like  ?
 like C:\> MsBuild myproject.sln 
or C:\>myfolder\myproject\MsBuild myproject.sln ? Unfortunately, none of it is working

Answer (score 4):

As the error is trying to tell you, you should install .Net 3.5 or change the project to target a version that you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this has been a problem for others at times. See: [Visual Studio 2010: Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498624/visual-studio-2010-could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target-framework-netframewo)

It could be a different version or a problem with the path to that version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project physical path , If is to long , Copy project to some root directory folder with very short name. And try to build your project.